# Batch Gradient Descent for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've been following Andrew Ng CSC229 machine learning course, and am now covering logistic regression.  The goal is to maximize the log likelihood function and find the optimal values of theta to do so.  The link to the lecture notes is: [http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.ps][1] -pages 16-19.  Now the code below was shown on the course homepage (in matlab though--I converted it to python).

I'm applying it to a data set with 100 training examples (a data set given on the Coursera homepage for a introductory machine learning course).  The data has two features which are two scores on two exams.  The output is a 1 if the student received admission and 0 is the student did not receive admission.  The have shown all of the code below.  The following code causes the likelihood function to converge to maximum of about -62.  The corresponding values of theta are [-0.05560301  0.01081111  0.00088362].  Using these values when I test out a training example like [1,  30.28671077,  43.89499752] which should give a value of 0 as output, I obtain 0.576 which makes no sense to me.  If I test the hypothesis function with input [1, 10, 10] I obtain 0.515 which once again makes no sense.  These values should correspond to a lower probability.  This has me quite confused.

```
import numpy as np
import sig as s

def batchlogreg(X, y):
   max_iterations = 800
   alpha = 0.00001

   (m,n) = np.shape(X)

   X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, 1) 
   theta = np.array([0] * (n+1), 'float')
   ll = np.array([0] * max_iterations, 'float')

   for i in range(max_iterations):
       hx = s.sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
       d = y - hx
       theta = theta + alpha*np.dot(np.transpose(X),d)
       ll[i] = sum(y * np.log(hx) + (1-y) * np.log(1- hx))

   return (theta, ll)
```

Comment: The link doesn't work. Also, you should really post the relevant text in your question rather than just give a link to it anyway.

Comment: apologies here is a working version http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.ps

Comment: Have you tried a larger learning rate (`alpha`)? It's usually not **that** small, so you might not be training your model properly. Try `0.1, 0.001` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sigmoid function has:

```
sig(0) = 0.5
sig(x > 0) > 0.5
sig(x < 0) < 0.5
```

Since you get all probabilities above `0.5`, this suggests that you never make `X * theta` negative, or that you do, but your learning rate is too small to make it matter.

```
for i in range(max_iterations):
    hx = s.sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta)) # this will probably be > 0.5 initially
    d = y - hx # then this will be "very" negative when y is 0
    theta = theta + alpha*np.dot(np.transpose(X),d) # (1)
    ll[i] = sum(y * np.log(hx) + (1-y) * np.log(1- hx))
```

The problem is most likely at `(1)`. The dot product will be very negative, but your `alpha` is very small and will negate its effect. So `theta` will never decrease enough to properly handle correctly classifying labels that are `0`.

Positive instances are then only barely correctly classified for the same reason: your algorithm does not discover a reasonable hypothesis under your number of iterations and learning rate.

**Possible solution:** increase `alpha` and / or the number of iterations, or use [momentum](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sgd).

Comment: So I actually spent quite a bit of time playing around with values of alpha and number of iterations.  Basically at alpha = 0.1, I obtain all nan values for the log likelihood function.  At alpha = 0.01, I get some nan values, otherwise no convergence to max.  At alpha = 0.001 much the same.  At alpha = 0.0001, there seems to be convergence to -784 and -478, and also a number of nan values are produced.  But still not stable.  Lowering alpha to the value shown finally produces no nan values and a steady convergence to -62.

Comment: And also the theta produced for larger alpha gives me really bad outputs from the logistic function.  Everything is 0.  The current alpha used finally gave me a stable output although the values are stuck between 0.5 and 0.77.

Comment: Can you try using float64 for your arrays please? Also, don't accept this until it works.

Comment: I change array values to 'float64' doesn't change much unfortunately.  I mapped the values in the interval 0.5 - 0.77 to 0 - 10 and it should give label of 1 for hypothesis > 0.58.  It seems to predict all the examples very well.  Otherwise, I don't really know whats else could be going wrong.  Equations all seem correct.  I've tried changing alpha and the number of iterations  --- and this is the best result I've found.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could be confusing probabilities with assignments.

The probability will be a real number between 0.0 and 1.0.  A label will be an integer (0 or 1).  Logistic regression is a model that provides the probability of a label being 1 given the input features.  To obtain a label value, you need to make a decision using that probability.  An easy decision rule is that the label is 0 if the probability is less than 0.5, and 1 if the probability is greater than or equal to 0.5.

So, for the example you gave, the decisions would both be 1 (which means the model is wrong for the first example where it should be 0).

Comment: Yeah I understand that the hypothesis will output a probability that the student receives admission given the particular input vector.  Although would it be reasonable to make the following decision such as if probability is less than 0.6 than it corresponds to 0.  Otherwise it corresponds to 1.  Then that would for the most part be reasonable.  But not that intuitive since you would expect high scores such as [1, 95, 96] to give 0.9 probability instead of 0.77 which is what I'm getting.

Comment: To be more specific, the probabilities I am obtaining for arbitrary inputs range between 0.5 to 0.77.  Is this normal or a strange thing ?

Comment: Ah ok.  So, the short answer is 'I don't know'.  The long answer is that your probabilities don't have to be well calibrated for the decision rule to still be good.  So long as high-scoring exams lead to higher probability of admission (usually), you can still decide between two things, even if the difference isn't all that large.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same question and found the reason.

Normalize X first or set a scale-comparable intercept like 50.

Otherwise contours of cost function are too "narrow". A big alpha makes it overshoot and a small alpha fails to progress.